# Как вызвать метод из одного файла в другом?

Tags: c++, наследование

Решил раскидать классы по файлам, чтобы было приятнее писать.

Есть данный код:

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "LoginForm.h"
int main()
{
    LoginField _login;
    PasswordField _password;
    _login.Rec();
    _password.Rec();
}
```

`LoginField` и `PasswordField` являются наследниками от класса `LoginForm`:

```cpp
//LoginForm.h
#pragmaonce
class LoginForm { std::string _password_correct; std::string _what_to_enter[3]; void Save(); bool PasswordCheck(std::string a);  std::string Enter(); void Rec(); void WhatToEnter();};
class PasswordField :public LoginForm { void Rec(); void WhatToEnter(); };
class LoginField :public LoginForm { void Rec(); void WhatToEnter(); };
```

Метод `void Rec();` переопределяется, при этом используя объявленный в родительском классе метод `Enter();` и также переопределенный метод `WhatToEnter();`

```cpp
//LoginForm.cpp
#include "LoginForm.h"
class LoginForm
{
public:
    string _password_correct;
    string _what_to_enter[3];
    LoginForm() {}
    ~LoginForm() {}
    void Save();
    bool PasswordCheck(string a)
    {
        size_t _is_password_correct = a.find_first_not_of(_password_correct);
        int _error_count = 0;
        _error_count += (size(a) < 6 || size(a) > 10) ? 1 : 0;
        _error_count += (_is_password_correct != string::npos) ? 1 : 0;
        return (_error_count > 0) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    string Enter()
    {
        ifstream PasswordCorrect("PasswordCorrect");
        PasswordCorrect >> _password_correct;
        PasswordCorrect.close();
        string _password;
        string _password_check;
        do
        {
            do
            {
                CC();
                cout << "Введите" << this->_what_to_enter[0] << ".\nДлина" << _what_to_enter[1] << "должна составлять от 6 до 10 символов,\nсодержать только буквы латинского алфавита и цифры.\n" << _what_to_enter[2] << "чувствителен к регистру.\n\n";
                getline(cin, _password);
                cout << endl;
                if (!PasswordCheck(_password))
                {
                    CC();
                    cout << "Введены некорректные данные. Пожалуйста повторите попытку.\n\n";
                    PP();
                }
            } while (!PasswordCheck(_password));
            if (_what_to_enter[0] == " пароль")
            {
                CC();
                cout << "Подтвердите пароль:\n\n";
                cin >> _password_check;
                cout << endl;
                if (_password_check != _password)
                {
                    CC();
                    cout << "Пароли не совпадают! Повторите ввод.\n\n";
                    PP();
                }
            }
            else _password_check = _password;
        } while (_password_check != _password);
        for (int i(0); i < size(_password); i++)
        {
            _password[i] = (char)((int)_password[i] + 35);
        }
        return _password;
    }
    void WhatToEnter() {};
    void Rec() {};
};
void LoginForm::Save()
{
    ofstream AdminInfo;
    CC();
    if (_what_to_enter[0] != " пароль") AdminInfo.open("AdminInfo");
    else
    {
        AdminInfo.open("AdminInfo", ios_base::app); AdminInfo << endl;
    }
    AdminInfo << _what_to_enter[2];
    AdminInfo << Enter();
    cout << _what_to_enter[2] << "сохранен!";
    AdminInfo.close();
}
class PasswordField : public LoginForm
{
public:
    void Rec()
    {
        WhatToEnter();
        Save();
    }
    void WhatToEnter()
    {
        _what_to_enter[0] = " пароль";
        _what_to_enter[1] = " пароля ";
        _what_to_enter[2] = "Пароль ";
    }
};
class LoginField : public LoginForm
{
public:
    void Rec()
    {
        WhatToEnter();
        Save();
    }
    void WhatToEnter()
    {
        _what_to_enter[0] = " логин";
        _what_to_enter[1] = " логина ";
        _what_to_enter[2] = "Логин ";
    }
};
```

Соответственно проблема в том, что в main.cpp при создании объектов классов `LoginField` и `PasswordField` и попытке вызвать у них метод `Rec();` я наблюдаю ошибку

> E0265  функцию "LoginField::Rec" (объявлено в строке 9 из "C:\Users\andre\source\repos\Ex_2\LoginForm.h") недоступно

Памагити.

Comment: Забыли `public:` в `LoginForm.h`. В `LoginForm.cpp` `class LoginForm` писать нельзя. Только определения функций а-ля `void LoginForm::Save() {...};`.

Comment: спасибо, я не знал этого. помогло. а про паблик, да, забыл)